# Query Oracle for running sql and value of bind variables

Tags: oracle, bind, trace

If I run the SQL in Fig. 1 below, it may return something like this:

```
Select fname, lname from name_tbl where nam_key = :key
```

Without using some fancy DBA trace utility, how can I query an Oracle system table to find the value of the bind variable “:key”?

*Figure 1.  - List the current running sql statement.*

```
select sid, username, sql_text  
from v$session,   
       v$sqltext  
 where sql_address    = address   
   and sql_hash_value = hash_value  
order by sid, piece;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select name, value_string
from v$sql_bind_capture
where sql_id = your_query_id
```

Upd. or, of course:

```
select sql_id, value_string
from v$sql_bind_capture
where name = ':key'
```